# I get an error when I use array!

Tags: errors

```
\begin{array}{rcl} 
f: R^3 & \to & R \\ 
(x,y,z) & \to & x + y + z \\ 
f(x,y,z) & = & x + y + z 
\end{array}
```

I inserted this code to my latex but it won't compile. It gives me following errors:

> ! Missing $ inserted.$ \begin{array}{rcl}
>
> ! Missing $ inserted.$ ...z \ f(x,y,z) & = & x + y + z \end{array}

I am not sure what I did wrong...

Comment: array has to be used in math mode

Comment: It is impossible to say exactly what you have done wrong as you did not show a complete document, so haven't shown the incorrect  context that led to the error.

Comment: As David points out, the error message`Missing $ inserted.$ \begin{array}{rcl}` means that you did not enter math mode, when you should have.

Comment: @user3000482 If you solved it onw your own: congratulations.  But please: answer your own question yourself and mark it solved.

Comment: @Jan the chance that a missing `$` error hadn't previously shown up as a duplicate was small:-)